# How do I wait for a .map() with asynchronous calls to finish before moving on?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, firebase, ecmascript-6

I have an array of `Picture` objects. I iterate over them using `.map()` so I can upload each of them to my firebase-storage. After the upload of a `Picture` has completed, I want to get the URL of the `Picture` and put it in an another array.

Once all the uploads are finished, and I have a complete array of URLs, I want to `db.push()` data to my database.

The problem is the `db.push()` starts *before* all my pictures have finished uploading!

How I can make the `db.push()` wait until the `.map()` is properly finished?

```
    UploadForm(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          const db = firebase.database().ref('app').child('cards');
          const userId = this.props.user;

          //the stuff from the Form
          const titel = this.titelInput.value;
          const grabtiefe = this.grapTiefeVonInput.value +" - " + this.grapTiefeBisInput.value;
          const transportbreite = this.transportbreiteVonInput.value + " - " + this.transportbreiteBisInput.value;
          const transporthoehe = this.transporthoeheVonInput.value + " - " + this.transporthoeheBisInput.value;
          const gewicht = this.GewichtdesArtikelsInput.value;
          const preis = this.priceInput.value;
          const desc = this.descInput.value;
          const adresse = this.props.address;
          const ort = this.props.ort;
          const mobil = this.props.mobil;
          const festnetz = this.props.festnetz


          const array = []
          const pictures = this.state.pictures[0]
          const keys = Object.keys(pictures)

          //the map function start to upload an Array of Pics and gets its URL and Pushes it to an Array. 
          // after this the map funciton sets the array to this.state.Arr  
          keys.map((key) => {
              const picture = pictures[key]
              firebase.storage().ref('images').child('artikelimgaes/'+userId).child('artikel/')
              .child(titel).child(picture.name).put(picture)
              .then(()=>{
                firebase.storage().ref('images').child('artikelimgaes/'+userId).child('artikel/').child(titel).child(picture.name)
                .getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                  const imgUrl = url;
                  array.push(url)
                  this.setState({Arr : array})
                })
              })
          })

          // now the Upload of all Data should start 
            const coordinaten = this.state.cords;
            const images = this.state.Arr
            const mainImage = this.state.Arr[0]
            db.push({
                      grabtiefe: grabtiefe,
                      transportbreite: transportbreite,
                      transporthoehe: transporthoehe,
                      cardHeading:titel ,
                      cardPreis: preis,
                      cardDesc: desc,
                      gewicht: gewicht,
                      address: adresse,
                      ort: ort,
                      gemietet: 0,
                      cords: coordinaten,
                      mobil:mobil ,
                      festnetz: festnetz,
                      imageArr: images,
                      imageUrl: mainImage,
                      gebiet: this.state.gebiet,
                      bundesland: this.state.bundesland,
                      uid: userId,

                    })
                    this.setState({
                      redirect: true
                    })

                }

      }
```

Comment: `return` the firebase promise, them wrap the mapped promise array into `Promise.all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible aproaches for this problem.

You could put the upload function in the `setState` callback

```
this.setState({Arr : array}, () => {
  // now the Upload of all Data should start 
} )
```

**edit using promises**

```
let keysPromises = keys.map(
  key =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const picture = pictures[key];
      firebase
        .storage()
        .ref("images")
        .child("artikelimgaes/" + userId)
        .child("artikel/")
        .child(titel)
        .child(picture.name)
        .put(picture)
        .then(() => {
          firebase
            .storage()
            .ref("images")
            .child("artikelimgaes/" + userId)
            .child("artikel/")
            .child(titel)
            .child(picture.name)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(url => {
              const imgUrl = url;
              array.push(url);
              this.setState({ Arr: array }, resolve());
            });
        });
    })
);

Promise.all(keysPromises).then(() => {
  // now the Upload of all Data should start
});
```

Comment: thank you for answering me, but this is in the map funciton, so the upload would start as often as there is something in the array to map to, or ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing multiple calls to `put()` and `getDownloadURL()` and you want to wait until all these calls have processed before going on to do other work.

This would be fine if these calls were *synchronous*, that is execution waits until the function completes before moving on, but they are not.

You can tell because they both return a `promise` meaning they are *asynchronous*; therefore, execution continues without waiting.

So that is the problem. How do we fix it?

The trick here is to use a feature of the JS Promise called `Promise.all()`. This takes an array of promises and returns a single promise of its own. Once the array of promises have all resolved (or one of them has rejected) then the single composite promise is resolved or rejected.

If you are using modern JS then this is made really easy by using the new `async` / `await` syntax.

You would recast your code so it looks something like this:

**Warning: Untested Code**

```
const getFirebase = pictureName =>
  firebase
    .storage()
    .ref('images')
    .child('artikelimgaes/' + this.props.user)
    .child('artikel/')
    .child(titel)
    .child(pictureName)

const getImageUrls = async keys => {
  const pictures = this.state.pictures[0]
  const keys = Object.keys(pictures)
  const picture = pictures[key]
  await Promise.all(keys.map(key => getFirebase(picture.name).put(picture)))
  await Promise.all(keys.map(key => getFirebase(picture.name).getDownloadURL(picture)))
}

const UploadForm = async event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const db = firebase
    .database()
    .ref('app')
    .child('cards')

  //the stuff from the Form
  const titel = this.titelInput.value
  const grabtiefe = this.grapTiefeVonInput.value + ' - ' + this.grapTiefeBisInput.value
  const transportbreite = this.transportbreiteVonInput.value + ' - ' + this.transportbreiteBisInput.value
  const transporthoehe = this.transporthoeheVonInput.value + ' - ' + this.transporthoeheBisInput.value
  const gewicht = this.GewichtdesArtikelsInput.value
  const preis = this.priceInput.value
  const desc = this.descInput.value
  const adresse = this.props.address
  const ort = this.props.ort
  const mobil = this.props.mobil
  const festnetz = this.props.festnetz

  // get all the picture urls and save them to state.
  this.setState({ Arr: await getImageUrls() })

  // now the Upload of all Data should start
  const coordinaten = this.state.cords
  const images = this.state.Arr
  const mainImage = this.state.Arr[0]
  db.push({
    grabtiefe: grabtiefe,
    transportbreite: transportbreite,
    transporthoehe: transporthoehe,
    cardHeading: titel,
    cardPreis: preis,
    cardDesc: desc,
    gewicht: gewicht,
    address: adresse,
    ort: ort,
    gemietet: 0,
    cords: coordinaten,
    mobil: mobil,
    festnetz: festnetz,
    imageArr: images,
    imageUrl: mainImage,
    gebiet: this.state.gebiet,
    bundesland: this.state.bundesland,
    uid: this.props.user
  })
  this.setState({
    redirect: true
  })
}
```

Using the `getImageUrls` function, I have split your single `map` into two. The first `map` does the job of putting all the pictures into `firebase`. Each put returns a promise which the `map` returns as an array of promises. This array is then `await`ed, that is the code execution waits until all the promises have been resolved. We can now do the same trick with the calls to `getDownloadURL()`.

Note that if you want to use the `await` keyword in a function then the function must be marked as `async`. You can see that happening in the `getImageUrls` function.

When a function is marked with `async` then it will always return a promise, no matter what is happening inside the function. This *implicit* promise is only auto-resolved when the function completes, in this case when all the promises in both the arrays have resolved. It waits because we are awaiting both the calls to `Promise.all()`

So now we need to make sure that the single implicit promise returned by the `async` `getImageUrls()` function has resolved before moving on to do our other work. So we need to `await` this promise as well, which means we need to mark the UploadForm` function as async to allow for this.

The end result should be a nice array of pictureUrls returned from the getImageUrls() function. You can now use this array to set your state before carrying on to your db work, safe in the knowledge that all your pictures have been safely stored in firebase.

Comment: Wow im amazed. Thank you so much for explaining me all of this. I'm actually a little bit overwhelmed by how kind this community is